# Shifting history in command-pattern with undo/redo?

Tags: java, arrays, history, undo, command-pattern

I'm having a problem concerning a command pattern with undo/redo function. The simple problem is, when my history is full, I want to remove the least recently used command from the history and add the new one on execute.

I got this code snippet from my professor:

```
public class CommandHistory implements CommandInterface{

private static final int MAX_COMMANDS = 2;

private Command[] history = new Command[MAX_COMMANDS];


private int current = -1;

@Override
public void execute(Command command) {
    current++;

    if (current == MAX_COMMANDS){                     // if full, then shift
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COMMANDS - 1; i++){
            history[i] = history[i+1];
        }

    }
    history[current] = command;
    history[current].execute();
}
```

In really doubt the **if-clause** is incorrect, because the current command index remains 2 and only command at index 0 is shifted to 1. But he says this is the way to go. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop itself is fine, but two problems:

1. You're quite correct that when `current == MAX_COMMANDS` is true and you do the loop, `current` is incorrect and needs adjusting.
2. From a maintenance perspective, `current == MAX_COMMANDS` is the wrong comparison, it should be `current == history.length`. (Otherwise, it's easy to change the initialization of `history` to use something other than `MAX_COMMANDS` but forget to change every check like `current == MAX_COMMANDS`.)

I would check `current` **before** incrementing it, and only increment it if you're not shifting the contents down:

```
public void execute(Command command) {

    if (current == history.length - 1){                     // if full, then shift
        for (int i = 0; i < history.length - 1; i++) {
            history[i] = history[i+1];
        }
    } else {
        current++;
    }
    history[current] = command;
    history[current].execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This sounds more reasonable indeed, but don't I have to reset the current-counter? If we say we went through the loop with current = 2, wouldn't the next loops always cause history[0] = history[1] and history[1] = history[2] like before, so the index history[0] is never used?

Comment: @Blixxen: Nope. When saving the first command, `current` is `-1`, the test is false, and you do `current++` to make it `0` and store the command there. When saving the next, `current` is `0`, the test is false, you do `current++` to make it `1` and you store the command there. When saving the next, `current` is `1` and so the test is **true** and you do `history[0] = history[1]` in the loop (which only runs once), then store the new command at `current`, which is still `1`.

Comment: My bad. Thank you, sir!